# How to get the searche result of google map

Tags: google-maps

I want to get the search result of Google map .
for example ,
When we go to http://maps.google.com/ ,and search restaurant + California .
There will appear many red dot in the map ,If will click one of them ,it will pop up a layer ,and show some information about some merchant ,such as phone number ,review ,address ,website .These information is what I want .

I don't whether  it is possible to get all the search result   .

Thanks 
Gary

Answer (score 0):

Currently Google Maps API does not offer this kind of information, maybe they will in the future...who knows.

Lewis